# Object.GetType() doesn't work with dynamic params

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm learning C# and I'm trying to understand how functions with dynamic params works and I have the following example:

```
    Type[] GetTypes(params object[] args)
    {
        Type[] types = new Type[args.Length];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            types[i] = args.GetType();
            Console.WriteLine(types[i].ToString());
        }
            
        return types;
    }
    
    void MyFunction(params object[] args)
    {
        foreach (var type in GetTypes(args))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(type.ToString());
        }
    }
    
    MyFunction(56, true, 45.9, "testing types deduction");
```

The problem I dound here is that the deduction is not correctly cause the output is:

```
>System.Object[] 
>System.Object[] 
>System.Object[] 
>System.Object[] 
>System.Object[] 
>System.Object[] 
>System.Object[] 
>System.Object[]
```

And was expecting something like

```
>System.Int32 
>System.Bool 
>System.Double 
>System.String 
>System.Int32 
>System.Bool 
>System.Double 
>System.String
```

Is there any way to fix this or there is a different way to get the specific type received by parameter in args?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mistakenly wrote `types[i] = args.GetType();` when you should have written `types[i] = args[i].GetType();`.